Issue with TON payment, fails sometimes and goes through other time
I am trying to send payments on the TON network and relying on NodeJs, transaction fails most times and goes through some other time.
All responses is highly important and appreciated.
I am making use of these libraries:
const { mnemonicToWalletKey } = require("@ton/crypto");
const { getHttpEndpoint } = require("@orbs-network/ton-access");
const { WalletContractV4, TonClient, fromNano, internal } = require("@ton/ton");

const payoutCustomer = async (props) => {
    const { toAddress, amount, comment } = props
    const key = await mnemonicToWalletKey(mnemonic.split(" "));
    const wallet = WalletContractV4.create({ publicKey: key.publicKey, workchain: 0 });

    // initialize ton rpc client on mainnet
    const endpoint = await getHttpEndpoint();
    const client = new TonClient({ endpoint });

    // make sure wallet is deployed
    if (!await client.isContractDeployed(wallet.address)) {
        return {
            resCode: 100,
            message: "wallet is not deployed"
        }
    }

    const walletContract = client.open(wallet);
    const seqno = await walletContract.getSeqno();
    await walletContract.sendTransfer({
        secretKey: key.secretKey,
        seqno: seqno,
        messages: [
            internal({
                to: toAddress,
                value: `${amount}`,
                body: comment, 
                bounce: false,
            })
        ]
    });

    // wait until confirmed
    let currentSeqno = seqno;
    while (currentSeqno == seqno) {
        await sleep(1500);
        currentSeqno = await walletContract.getSeqno();
    }
    return {
        resCode: 200,
        message: 'Transaction confirmed'
    }

}

Thanks in anticipation.
